# Finding an unknown column of a singular matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a question regarding a singular matrix and unknown values a,b,c,d.

\begin{bmatrix}4&a&-5&8\\3&b&-5&7\\9&c&5&-4\\0&d&2&-2\end{bmatrix}

I know that the determinant of a singular matrix is zero, so the following are possible values for a,b,c,d:

\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\9\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-5\\-5\\5\\2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}8\\7\\-4\\-2\end{bmatrix}

My question is, how can I find the other possible values for a,b,c,d? I tried using cofactor expansion and ended up with an equation of four unknown values summing up to zero, so I don't think that's the right approach. Could I get a suggestion on what I should try instead?

Comment: What do you know about vector spaces? If a column is contained in the vector space generated by all the other columns of the matrix then the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Expand (minors!) the determinant down the second column in the standard way and get a linear criterion, which is necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computing the determinant of $A$ we obtain
$$
\det(A)= - (2c - 45d - 46b + 30a).
$$
Hence $A$ is singular if and only if $30a-46b+2c-45d=0$.